# ORM with GUI editor like ADO.Entoty for Android development

Tags: android, orm

is there any ORM for android like ADO Entity with gui editor plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an ORM that supports JPA annotations like [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com) you can (in Eclipse) try to install the JPA Diagram Editor (`Help > Install new software... > Juno release site > Web, XML... > Dali JPA Tools - JPA Diagram Editor`). Configure your project as JPA project and you can [begin to use the diagram editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JPA_Diagram_Editor_Project_Tutorial). You can even install the [JBoss Hibernate tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/) ("Nightly" for Juno), configure your project as Hibernate project and use the [map diagram](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#map_diagram) - even when you don't use Hibernate in the final product.

I think this is the closest you can get.

Honestly, I don't think the diagrams are terribly helpful when creating new entities. They are quite helpful for forensic analysis of larger legacy projects (which would be untypical for Android projects). The JPA perspective with its tools is nice when creating entities (no need to explcitely learn and remember every subtlety of the annotations); the possibilities of the Hibernate perspective to execute HQL/JPQL are great (but not helpful for Android development yet).

Answer (score 0):

I use [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/)  but it haven't gui editor...